# ASP.net - Get Page VirtualPage from Class Declaration

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

i'm trying to get a class VirtualPath of a class.
When the class is instantiated, i can call `this.AppRelativeVirtualPath;` (or, in VB `Me.AppRelativeVirtualPath`) that would give me "~/content/page.aspx".

Now, i need to call THE CLASS, not the instance, to get that path. Something like this:

```
public class Page : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public static string GetPath() { return Page.AppRelativeVirtualPath; }
}
```

But i can't do it, because "AppRelativeVirtualPath" is non-shared method.
What would be the method to call it?

I need something that gives me the same result as this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.ui.templatecontrol.apprelativevirtualpath(v=vs.110).aspx

EDITING AFTER TIM'S ANSEER

The specific classes i wrote, using his code are like this:

```
Namespace Web.Pages
    Public Class Dir
        Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
        Public Shared Function GetPath() As String
            Dim page As Web.Pages.Dir = TryCast(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Handler, Web.Pages.Dir)
            If (Page Is Nothing) Then Return "" Else Return page.AppRelativeVirtualPath
        End Function
    End Class
End Namespace
```

And that (WHERE I WANT IT TO RESOLVE):

```
Namespace Web.Pages
    Public Class MainPage
        Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
        Public ReadOnly Property LinkToDir() As String
            Get
                Return Web.Pages.Dir.GetPath()
            End Get
        End Property
    End Class
End Namespace
```

See, the context is on the "MainPage" that calls a static method on "Dir" page for it ("Dir") to return it's ASP page virtual address (that would be "~/content/dir.aspx").

How can i achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`HttpContext.Current.Handler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.currenthandler.aspx) to get the page instance from a static/Shared context:

```
public static string GetPath() 
{  
    Page page = HttpContext.Current.Handler as Page;
    if (page != null)
        return page.AppRelativeVirtualPath;
    return null;
}
```

VB.NET:

```
Public Shared Function GetPath() As String
    Dim page = TryCast(HttpContext.Current.Handler, Page)
    If page IsNot Nothing Then
        Return page.AppRelativeVirtualPath
    Else
        Return Nothing
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Didn't work. The "GetPath()" function keep returning nothing.

Comment: @SammuelMiranda: from where do you call it? It must be from an actual page-lifecycle.

Comment: no, i need to call it from another page - the active page calls a static method on another class (that is also a page, but not online yet).

Comment: @SammuelMiranda: then it should not return null because the "active" page would be the `HttpContext.Current.Handler`. Have you used the debugger?

Comment: yes - the function you wrote gives no erros, but it always falls on the "ELSE" part (the RETURN NOTHING). Because PAGE is NOTHING returning from the trycast

Comment: i'm taking that it's impossible to achieve?

Comment: @SammuelMiranda: if you call it from the lifecycle of another page(f.e. in `Page_Load`) `HttpContext.Current.Handler` returns the instance of that page. If you're calling `LinkToDir` or `GetPath` from outside of a page's lifecycle(f.e. from a winforms application or via webmethod) there is no current-handler, hence it's null.

Comment: yes, i understood that - that's exactly my problem - i need to find what is the virtual path for ANOTHER page that is not set on.

Comment: isn't there a way? how does the server knows what class to load when the ASPX is called?